# c# ping between two ip addresses

Tags: c#, server, ping

How can i check if two servers are connected from a third server in c#?
I am in server A and i want to know if Server B and Server C are connected.
I only have the code to check if I am connected to server B or C.
What I have:

```
public bool AreConnected(string ip)
{
    bool connected= false;
    Ping p = new Ping();
    try
    {                
        PingReply reply = p.Send(ip);
        connected = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: surely if you can connect to both then they can be connected to each other

Comment: @Cjen1, Not necessary. There might be a firewall rule preventing them from connecting to each other.

Comment: I already know that I have connection to B and C, but how can i be sure that B and C are connected too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used PsExec and works fine, below my code maybe could help someone else,

```
public bool IsPingable(string servA, string servB)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "\\Resources\\PsExec.exe";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + servA + " ping " + servB + " -n 1";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (!output.Contains("100% loss"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typically, when someone else provides the answer that fixed your problem, you'd accept their answer. If you think your code is helpful, you could add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best approach, and it requires admin privileges on machine B, but it works.

Use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). This tool allows you to run a command on a remote machine.

Create a command line program that take the ip address as a command line parameter, pings the ip address and outputs the result.

Then run PsExec (from C# code) to execute such program on machine B and collect the result (from code also).

You will need to use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx) to be able to execute the PsExec command from C# code.

Comment: Thanks, but Im trying to get it with full c# code without installing or downloading anything else